# Processing commands result

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to process results of one command but stuck at some point.

My code is like

```
    for i in $(command)
    do
      if [ -z "$i" ]; then 
        echo "empty"
      else
        do-some-stuff
      fi
    done
```

It works fine except one case: when command doesn't return any result. I want to echo a text that command is empty but have no idea how to do it. The code above isn't working.

Comment: What command are you running and what are you doing with the results? This loop is really unidiomatic and unsafe. Unidiomatic because explicitly looping over command output can often be replaced with bulk operations like piping to grep; unsafe because the output is subject to wildcard expansion and could surprisingly be affected by what files are in the current directory (!). If you share some details we can suggest a better way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assign the result of your command to a variable.
2. Check whether the command completed successfully by inspecting `$?`, which contains the
   exit code of the last command (zero for success, non-zero for
   failure).
3. Ensure the result is not empty before starting iteration. You can always use double-bracket syntax to do this if you're not
   concerned with portability to shells that don't support Bash.

```sh
result=$(find $PWD -type f) # Your command
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Command failed."
elif [[ $result ]]; then
    for i in $result; do
      echo "do something with $i"
    done
else
    echo "no result: something went wrong"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result to a variable before looping over it.

```
result=$(command)
if [ -z "$result" ]; then
    echo "empty"
else
    for i in $result
    do
        do-some-stuff "$i"
    done
fi
```

Comment: Thank you but I prefer another solution :)